# Hibernate: overriding xml config file with another file

Tags: java, unit-testing, hibernate

I have a source tree composed of source and test classes. When I run the tests, I'd like to use `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` while when running the code I'd like to use a `validate` value instead of create.
I thought to use two config files, one with all the properties and containing hbm2ddl.auto set to validate, and another with hbm2ddl.auto set to create. I hoped that the following code would have allowed me to read from the tests the basic file and override the only hbm2ddl.auto propery, but it doesn't work (the value of hbm2ddl.auto is still the one read from hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration = configuration.
    configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
    addResource("hibernate-test.cfg.xml");
```

How can I have two different values for a property, without replicating the whole config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that when you have only a few values to override, one simple approach is to load the xml config as usual, and then call `setProperty` programmatically, like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration = configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```

hbm.xml files don't allow to override values with `addResource(...)` as I tried to do, the values are only added and not overridden

Comment: I'm trying to override `connection.url` by using `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addURL(urlForXmlWithOverrides)`, and getting the same results: the connection URL isn't being overridden. However, I'm finding it also doesn't work when there's no original value, i.e. the file passed to the `configure(URL)` method doesn't include that property at all. I'm therefore not sure that values even get added.  

Anyhow, I'll use your method—it's not particularly elegant, but at least it works. :-) Thanks.

Comment: I solved my problem by using the property name 'hibernate.connection.url' instead. Instead of `setProperty`, I read properties from a stream and used `Configuration.addProperties(Properties)`, but it's basically the same thing you're doing.  

In any case, it seems `addProperties` is different from the other 'add' methods, in that they add _properties_ instead of _mappings_. I haven't found out what this distinction is for; I'll post an answer if I do.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with trying to programmatically load another config. Work around i used was to have another hibernate.properties file (instead of xml config). You can set the alternate hibm2ddl value in this properties file and load it using following code:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile));
        configuration = new Configuration().setProperties(props);
```

Try and see if this works for you.

Imp: don't call configuration.configure().

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying: your method allows to load a different properties file, but I wanted to load a "base" properties file plus an additional one, which would override some properties. Isolved as I'm going to write